# Clustering Node.js on Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

Will a Node.js app on Bluemix automatically be scaled to run on multiple processors, or do I need to implement that myself using Node's clustering API?  And if I do use clustering, will there be more than one CPU available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: You need to use node cluster module to take full advantage of all cores in each instance. Or, you can also just increase the number of instances.

Long answer: Each instance of your application that you push to bluemix runs in a warden container. Resource control is managed by linux cgroups.  The number of cores per instance is not something you can control. Running a quick test on Bluemix, os.cpus() showed 4 cores. If you want to take advantage of all 4 cores, in your one Bluemix instance (warden container) of your node.js application, then you should use nodes cluster module.

Keep in mind, you can also just increase the number of instances (horizontal scaling), which could achieve near linear results depending on your bottleneck on use of external services. So if you have 3 instances, each of those instances has 4 cores, and the built-in load balancer distributes traffic among the 3 instances.

Answer (score 6):

The hybrid model that Ram suggested makes sense. You might want to do some benchmark to determine how many processes you want to run in one application container. You can use "cf app " to monitor the CPU utilization of each app instances under load, and if it's not fully consuming the CPU then it may make sense to spawn more processes.

However, please note -
* CPU might not be the bottleneck, in which case spawn more processes in the app container or scaling more app container instances won't help;
* The more processes you spawn in one container, the more memory it consumes, so make sure you do not spawn too many and exceed the allocated memory number (otherwise the app container will be killed).